# phantomjs: Save a base64 string as a file(png)

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

Yes I did it in Nodejs but I can't in PhantomJS.

```
imgContent = '...base64...string';
imgContent = imgContent.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");
chart_path = "/charts.png";

fs.write(chart_path, new Buffer(imgContent, 'base64'), 'w');
```

The error message:

**ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Buffer**

Comment: PhantomJs does not support Buffer object. Remember, PhantomJS is not node.js. It is Google Chrome javascript with some (but not all) of node.js functionality.

Comment: Curiously, It is neither Google Chrome nor node.js javascript.

Comment: The point is: How this can be done? I personaly solved this in another way.But I would like to use a clean solution if is possible.

Comment: @Tedi Çela, am facing the same issue. How could this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure is it best solution, but it works fine for me.

```
// ...

fs.write(chart_path, atob(imgContent), 'b');
```

Phantomjs version 2.1.1.